# What is the keyboard shortcut for accessing the main (hamburger) menu in Gedit?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, gedit, accessibility

What is the keyboard shortcut or accelerator keys for opening gedit's primary menu (the menu that appears when the three-line button `☰` at the top left)?

In older versions of the program, the key accelerators <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> could open the File, Edit, and Tools menus, respectively.

https://help.gnome.org/users/gedit/stable/gedit-shortcut-keys.html.en doesn't seem to list a way to achive this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Shortcuts list](https://help.gnome.org/users/gedit/stable/gedit-shortcut-keys.html.en#yelp--4) does include it, but in an obscure way:

> Open the file menu    <kbd>F10</kbd>

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe they removed the typical key accelerators.  The `F10` is so far away from reach that you might as well reach the hamburger menu faster with a malfunctioning mouse cursor.

Comment: and how do you navigate in that  menu? the arrow keys dont work (Evince on ubuntu 18)